# Jquery preventDefault() misbehaves

Tags: jquery

preventDefault() messes up the events I can handle on one specific page.
All I am trying to do is display a static progress bar. Inside the header div I've got links to other html documents and I want them loaded up and then displayed.

I am using this piece of jquery :

```
$("#header a").click(function(e){
    $('body').append('<div id="progress">Loading...</div>');
    e.preventDefault();
    loadPage(e.target.href);
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#progress').remove();
});
```

The problem is that, on the page that is loaded after clicking a link inside the header div, no other click event works on that page except the ones in the header. 
Firebug doesn't even catches clicks anymore outside the header.

Thank you!
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code as return false will do both ..`.preventDefault` and `stoppropagation`

```
("#header a").click(function(e){
    $('body').append('<div id="progress">Loading...</div>');    
    loadPage(e.target.href);
    $('#progress').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I use return false, everything else doesn't work. I am trying to do this, to show some kind of loading screen when switching pages. It works ok on PC without return false or prevetDefault(), but on a mobile browser, the loading screen is displayed only if preventDefault() is called before the load(). Thanks!